# Swift - Sort the content of NSSSet

Tags: ios, swift3, nsset

I am using Core Data to fetch the list of clinics, the clinics has relations named doctors mapped to Doctor entity.

My issue is, every time I fetch doctors, which is of type NSSSet, the record is fetched randomly, I want to sort it alphabetically using Doctor.name

I tried the following

```
self.doctorList = clinic.doctors?.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)])
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(NS)Set` is an unordered collection type.

To order a `Set` convert it to an array with the `allObjects` property and sort the array.

```
self.doctorList = (clinic.doctors!.allObjects as! [Doctor]).sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })
```

You can even ***sort*** the set directly but the result is always an array

```
self.doctorList = (clinic.doctors as! Set<Doctor>).sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })
```

And if the set is declared as native `Set<Doctor>` anyway you can omit the type cast.

I recommend to declare the `doctors` relationship as non-optional. If there is no associated doctor the set is empty. But a clinic without any doctor is very unlikely ;-)

Comment: I am getting an error which states `Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type ((Doctor, Doctor) -> Bool) 1. Expected an argument list of type '(by:(Doctor, Doctor) -> Bool)'`

Comment: I now get another error which says `Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type (by:(Doctor, Doctor) -> Bool)`

Comment: The current data fixture I got has many clinics without the doctor, and I still need to store the data. Hence making doctors relationship as non-optional does not work for me in my current scenario.

Comment: Yes, and I am trying to figure out, what could go wrong. :-(

Comment: Are you using an `NSManagedObject` subclass `Doctor`?

Comment: Yes, Indeed! I am using NSManagedObject

Comment: This is the usual way to sort a relationship NSSet.

Comment: You mean the way you have mentioned above?

Comment: Or can't I sort it while fetching the records?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148699/discussion-between-ibrahim-azhar-armar-and-vadian).

Comment: Yes, I'm using it very often. Alternatively fetch all doctors which belong to that clinic.

Comment: You are right, my bad that I had wrong data type defined for property doctorList when declaring it, after changing it to `var doctorList:[Doctor] = []` it worked. Thanks for your help.